# How to set environment variable of Google Chrome for Flutter 2 Web on Arch Linux

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, flutter-web, archlinux

Using `flutter doctor` I understand that flutter cant find google-chrome executable.
I'm using fish shell.
I set the environment variable in /. config/fish using the `set CHROME_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` command how doctor says, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Arch Linux, the executive file of the proprietary version of google chrome has the name `google-chrome-stable`, but flutter tries to find exactly `google-chrome`. Therefore, setting the environment variable for `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable` has no effect.

Therefore, to solve the problem, you need to create a link to `google-chrome-stable` with the name `google-chrome` using the command `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/local/bin/google-chrome`